# How is Sql Server able to use Clustered Index Columns as Seek Predicate when Seeking on Nonclustered Index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

Noticed a strange behavior and was hoping someone could point me to documentation or describe how this is even possible.

I have a table (A,B,C) with a clustered index (A,B) and a nonclustered index (A,C)

When performing a select with filters on all columns (A,B,C), the executed query plan shows that it was able to use the NonClustered index but has a seek predicate with all 3 columns (A,B,C)

Test Code:

```
DROP TABLE test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
CREATE TABLE test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
( 
    Key1 INT, 
    UnexpectedClusteredKey INT,
    NonClusteredKey INT
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Index on test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
(
    Key1,
    UnexpectedClusteredKey
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Index on test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
(
    Key1,
    NonClusteredKey
)

INSERT INTO test.tbl_IndexSeekTest VALUES (1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(1,5,1)

SELECT * FROM test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
WHERE Key1 = 1
AND NonClusteredKey = 1
AND UnexpectedClusteredKey = 1
```

[executed actual query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn1JL.png)

I would have expected it to use either the clustered index on (A,B) and with a residual predicate to filter C, or the nonClustered (A,C) with a residual predicate on B, I understand that no lookup is needed because both indexes are covering.

It being able to utilize all three columns is new behavior with my best guess being that because B is the next column in the ClusteredIndex that isn't all ready in the Nonclustered it is able to still utilize it as a seek predicate but I can't find that behavior described anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

For nonclustered indexes the row identifier (clustered index key in this case or rid if the table is a heap) is always present so it can do the lookup back to the row.

If the index is declared as unique this can be as an included column otherwise it will be added to the key columns of the nonclustered index.

This happens implicitly and behind the scenes.

So you write

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Index on test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
(
    Key1,
    NonClusteredKey
)
```

But what SQL Server actually creates internally is effectively the same as

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Index on test.tbl_IndexSeekTest
(
    Key1,
    NonClusteredKey,
    UnexpectedClusteredKey,
    ClusteredIndexUniqufier
)
```

The extra clustered index key columns that weren't explicitly part of the key get silently appended to the end so the full key is in fact unique.

As your clustered index is also not declared as unique in this case it also includes the [uniquifier](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2082/understanding-and-examining-the-uniquifier-in-sql-server/) column (which is another hidden key column that is in your clustered index).

In your case your entire nonclustered index fits on a single page. You can see this from running

```
SELECT
allocated_page_file_id AS PageFID
,allocated_page_page_id AS PagePID
FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('test.tbl_IndexSeekTest'), 2, NULL, 'DETAILED')
WHERE is_allocated = 1 AND page_type_desc = 'INDEX_PAGE';
```

To get the File and PageId (1,416 in my case) and plugging them into the below

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC PAGE(0, 1, 416, 3);
```

Which returns the following (if the index had any `include`-d columns these would also be shown but without the `(key)` annotation.

| FileId | PageId | Row | Level | Key1 (key) | NonClusteredKey (key) | UnexpectedClusteredKey (key) | UNIQUIFIER (key) | KeyHashValue | Row Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 416 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | (8f9675c9b743) | 16 |
| 1 | 416 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | (ccbf7a473afc) | 16 |
| 1 | 416 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | (54f80e2fe7f1) | 16 |
| 1 | 416 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 | (4bed645b2183) | 16 |
| 1 | 416 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | (d3aa1033fc8e) | 16 |

More details about this from Kalen Delaney ([Internet archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200713174049/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx))